# Taking data from multiple forms in a loop and insert into database in a loop

Tags: php, html

I have a form in a loop that iterates 4 times. I want to process and print the form data dynamically.

This is not showing the required output. Am I doing something wrong ?

**index.php**

```
<?php
for($i = 1; $i<5; $i++)
{
?>
<form action = 'index.php' method = 'post'>
<input type = 'text' name = 'name<?php echo $i; ?>'>

<?php
}
?>

<input type = 'submit' value = 'submit'>

<?php

for($i = 1; $i<5; $i++)
{
$namee = $_POST['name.$i'];
echo $namee;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line :

`$namee = $_POST['name.$i']; //you cannot concatenate variables this way`,

it should be (note where the single quote is):

`$namee = $_POST['name'.$i];`

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes not evaluate variables, you can use concatenation:

```
 $namee = $_POST['name'.$i];
```

Or double quotes

```
$namee = $_POST["name$i"];
```